# How to transform mongodb object id to online shop item number (item id)

Tags: mongodb

How to transform mongodb object id to online shop item number (item id)

For example i have the following ObjectId: 5eead40275d4c1719468ee81

If i just transform it from hex to dec it will be too long, we need unique item number for every position in online shop, we want it to be shorter and be able to find an object by the number.
I thought about taking timestamp part (first four bytes) and tranform it to dec, but maybe you guys have better ideas. I just use one server so i am not worried that timestamp might have duplicates.

I am surprised that none asked about that before.

Comment: How long is too long?

Comment: Well, no more than 7-8 numbers or letters

Comment: The ObjectID is 24 hexadecimal digits, which is 12 bytes.  8 numbers and letters can represent about 6 bytes max.  Half of the ObjectID would be lost.  If you want to be able to do any sort of searching based on _id, the item number would have to be based on the first 6 bytes of the ObjectID.  I don't think there is a reasonable way to ensure uniqueness in a value like that other than storing it in the document, at which point it's not really meaningful to base it on the ObjectID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package [short-mongo-id](https://github.com/treygriffith/short-mongo-id). it will generate short Id from the objectId

Comment: It will not work because this way i can't search by item id